Cluster Kubernetes limit schedule on nodes based on CPU
I have a Kubernetes EKS cluster, my apps consume a lot of CPU when they are starting, after that the consumption drops, so there is no need to use large requests but we use large limits, I would like to know if anyone knows how to always have 20% of Free CPU on the nodes, if it has less than that, block new pods from being allocated to it.
Thanks!
I see some articles but nothing help me.
